# std::setprecision function gives wrong result

Tags: c++, decimal-point

I have the following line to display `float` numbers with only 3 decimal digits:

```
myfile << dSet[i].probability[j] << setprecision(3);
```

It goes through 150 lines of data, and it prints all of them fine (3 digits as expected), except for some data (especially the very first data):

[image: decimal point]

It's ok for the `...e...` numbers, but for the others i'd like it to display only 3 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: How do you expect `setprecision()` to affect output *that has already happened*? (Try calling `setprecision()` **first**.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here,  the first is that you don't call
`setprecision` until *after* having output the first value, so
it gets output with the default precision, 6.

The second is that all of the other output you highlight *is* output with
a precision of 3: in all cases, there are three significant
digits.  The issue is that "precision" has different meanings
according to the output format.

From your output, I assume you are using the default output format, where precision means 
exactly that: the number of significant digits (and the choice of whether to use scientific format or fixed depends on the value).  With fixed or scientific format, precision means the
number of digits after the decimal, using fixed format, for example, your second highlighted entry would be `0.008` (which sounds like what you want), and the values in scientific format that you have would all be `0.000`.

If you want the smaller values to appear in scientific format, you might want to do the
test yourself, setting either fixed or scientific according to your critera.  (The criteria for the default format is that the exponent would be smaller than `-precision`.)

Comment: "The second is that all of the other output you highlight is output with a precision of 3".

If i placed it in the wrong place, then why some of the output is with a precision of 3? `setprecision` affects the next output if placed like that?

Comment: @AlaaM.`setprecision` affects all of the output which follows it.